# Built .jar file (built in Netbeans 11.2 maven) is not able to connect to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, maven, netbeans

I have built an application in Maven Netbeans. This application is taking all the data from the Jforms and Jdialog and storing it in MySQL. It is working fine while I am running this application in NetBeans, but it is not able to communicate with MySQL when I try to run the built jar file.

I have tried building the project with dependencies but it does not work.
The output when I am running from Netbeans is as follows: -

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Scanning for projects...


------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building CASYS_V3 3.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The POM for unknown.binary:AbsoluteLayout:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.18 is missing, no dependency information available

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ CASYS_V3 ---
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

pom file is as follows: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.mycompany.casys_v3.StartPage</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>CASYS_V3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Check for any runtime param that you have passed while running in Netbeans.

Comment: please share pom.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for the help. I have added all the dependencies in pom file. It is working now. The plugin is as follows: -

```
     <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.mycompany.casys_v3.StartPage</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id> 
          <phase>package</phase> <!-- packaging phase -->
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```